# Pontuação automática nas linhas de uma MultiLine TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

eu preciso de ajuda, é assim, eu tenho que gravar os dados de uma MultiLine TextBox para uma Base de Dados, o que já está a funcionar, mas eu tenho que fazer uma pontuação automática nessa informação que foi inserida pelo utilizador, vou dar um exemplo :

```
        Isto é a primeira frase; 
        Isto é a segunda frase; 
        Isto é a última frase.
```

A última frase vai ter que sempre conter um "." e as frases acima dessa vão ter que conter um ";", tem que ser feito automaticamente, caso o utilizador se esqueça, pois essa informação, vai ser mais tarde exportada para um documento Word e tem que conter essa pontuação.

Como é que eu faço com que o programa faça isso automaticamente ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o regex e fazer um replace

```
string pattern = @"\s+\n";
string input = @"Isto é a primeira frase 
Isto é a segunda frase  
Isto é a última frase";
Regex.Replace(input,pattern,";\r\n")+"."
```

Saida:

```
Isto é a primeira frase;
Isto é a segunda frase;
Isto é a última frase.
```

Veja funcionando em [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1QM7E1)

Answer (score 0):

Se for em tempo de execução, vai ter que procurar por javascript, aí já não posso te ajudar muito, porém, se for apenas na hora do `insert`, você pode executar o comando `replace`, trocando os caracteres de quebra de linha.

Ex: Se o conteúdo estiver em HTML:

```
texto.Replace("<br>",";<br>");
```

Se o texto estiver 'normal' dentro da string:

```
texto.Replace("\r",";\r");
```

Answer (score 0):

Para garantir que haverá os ";" eu faria o seguinte:

```
Texto.replace(";", "").replace("\n", ";\n");
```

E para o "." eu faria:

```
Texto.replace(".", "");
Texto.Insert(Texto.Length, ".")
```